# How can I make an appendable observable queue?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an array where I need to make single requests using very single data set of this array. The problem that I found difficult to solve was to schedule the calls. Means, only when a request finishes, the next request starts. I was looking for an RxJs queue, but I couldn't simply find a solution.

Example:

```
function makeRequest(body): Observable<any> {
   return someAsyncRequest(body);
}

array.forEach((entry) => {
    makeRequest(entry);
});

// This is just an example how the setup is. This code does not work. 
// What I need is a queue like feature in RxJs to append requests and wait before the previous one is finished.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have quite few options, but I suppose `concat` or `forkJoin` fits you best. `concat` calls second API only after previous completes, while `forkJoin` will do the same, but only if none of them errors. If any of them errors, it will not return anything.

Example with `concat`:

```
concat(...array.map(entry => makeRequest(entry)).subscribe()
```

p.s. import `concat` as static operator:

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs'
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have things go out one by one, but still receive all the results at once, i recommend concat -> reduce. looks like this:

```
concat(...array.map(entry => makeRequest(entry))).pipe(
  reduce((completed, curResponse) => completed.concat([curResponse]), [])
).subscribe(allResponses => console.log(allResponses))
```

this structure achieves the single emission that forkjoin will give you but will do the requests one by one and then gather them once all complete. if you want the results one by one as they complete though, then just concat gets the job done as shown by others

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoin can meet your requirment

‘forkJoin’ waits for each HTTP request to complete and group’s all the observables returned by each HTTP call into a single observable array and finally return that observable array.

```
  public requestDataFromMultipleSources(): Observable<any[]> {
    let response1 = this.http.get(requestUrl1);
    let response2 = this.http.get(requestUrl2);
    let response3 = this.http.get(requestUrl3);
    return forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]);
  }
```

subscribe to single observable array and save the responses separately.

```
 this.dataService.requestDataFromMultipleSources().subscribe(responseList => {
            this.responseData1 = responseList[0];
            this.responseData2 = responseList[1];
            this.responseData3 = responseList[2];
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[MDN Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) see this you can do it even without observable

```
Promise.all(array.map(item => makeRequest(item))).then(values =>{
     // your logic with recieved data    
     })
```

Comment: It seems like it does not retain the order and also not wait a single request. I have for example 5000 items and I want make a requests 1 by 1.

Comment: oh ok got what you were actually trying

Comment: I try to receive the response one by one and in the same order as I have the data in the array.

Comment: One interesting thing about Promise.all is that the order of the promises is maintained. from [free code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/promise-all-in-javascript-with-example-6c8c5aea3e32/)